# Custom Error Message for Event Receiver in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, error, event-receivers

I want users to upload the .doc files only in the document library.

To do so, I have developed an event receiver in Visual Studio 2010.

My code is as follows:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   try
   {

       base.ItemAdding(properties);
       EventFiringEnabled = false;

       if (!properties.AfterUrl.EndsWith("doc"))
       {
           properties.ErrorMessage = "You are allowed to updload only .doc files";
           properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
           properties.Cancel = true;

       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
       properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
       properties.Cancel = true;
   }

}
```

The code is referred from this example.

My problem is that while I am uploading non-doc files it is preventing but with the system error message not the user friendly as defined in properties.ErrorMessage.

Error is as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9qrZ.png)

How do I solve this?

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the catch ErrorMessage that is showing?

Comment: Yes I am posting the image... @RobertLindgren

Comment: That error message looks like you are not successfully capturing the error at all

Comment: First I put outside the `catch()` statement after I got an example from the MSDN site and I preferred to do that..

Comment: What to do for capturing error successfully? @RobertLindgren

Comment: Could be that you are catching it, but your web config does not allow you to view the correct error message (as the error message actually tells you). Check the ULS logs to see if it records your error message

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventpropertiesbase.status.aspx) of SPItemEventProperties to redirect the user to a custom page:

```
properties.Cancel = true;
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl; 
properties.RedirectUrl = "/_layouts/MyApp/CustomErrorPage.aspx?Error=" + errorMessage;
```

Of course, you have to provision the CustomErrorPage.aspx and write the logic for it.
There are some problems with ItemDeleting event, but this should not affect you:
http://sharesilver.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/sharepoint-bugs-1-item-deleting-event-receiver/

Answer (score 0):

First do a check for if(properties.ListItem.File!=null) to determine if listitem has file associated with it.

```
 properties.RedirectUrl = properties.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/errorpage.aspx";
 properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
 properties.Cancel = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg981880.aspx#UsingEventReceiversInSPFPart2_CancelingAndRedirecting